# How to use my Entities and Entity Managers in Symfony 2 Console Command?

Tags: php, console, symfony

I want to a few terminal commands to my Symfony2 application. I've gone through the [example in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console.html), but I couldn't find out how to access my settings, my entity manager and my entities here. In the constructor, I get the container (which should yield me access to settings and entities) using

```
$this->container = $this->getContainer();
```

But this call generates an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getKernel() on a non-object in /Users/fester/Sites/thinkblue/admintool/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php on line 38

Basically, in ContainerAwareCommand->getContainer() the call to

```
$this->getApplication()
```

returns NULL and not an object as expected. I guess that I left some important step out, but which one? And how will I finally be able to use my settings and entities?

Comment: i am having the same error when (and I attempt to access `getContainer()` inside of `MyCommand->execute()` but still get the same fatal error. my `CommandTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase` and I run it via `phpunit -c app src/CompanyName/MyBundle/Tests/Commands/MyCommandTest.php` any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I think you should not retrieve the container in the constructor directly. Instead, retrieve it in the `configure` method or in the `execute` method. In my case, I get my entity manager just at the start of the `execute` method like this and everything is working fine (tested with Symfony 2.1).

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    // Code here
}
```

I think that the instantiation of the application object is not done yet when you are calling `getContainer` in your constructor which result in this error. The error comes from the `getContainer` method tyring to do:

```
$this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
```

Since `getApplication` is not an object yet, you get the a error saying or are calling a method `getKernel` on a non-object.

**Update**: In newer version of Symfony, `getEntityManager` has been deprecated (and could have been removed altogether by now). Use `$entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();` instead. Thanks to [Chausser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445160/chausser) for pointing it.

**Update 2**: In Symfony 4, auto-wiring can be used to reduce amount of code needed.

Create a `__constructor` with a `EntityManagerInterface` variable. This variable will be accessible in the rest of your commands. This follows the auto-wiring Dependency Injection scheme.

```
class UserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand { 
  private $em; 

  public function __construct(?string $name = null, EntityManagerInterface $em) { 
    parent::__construct($name); 

    $this->em = $em;
  } 

  protected function configure() { 
    **name, desc, help code here** 
  }

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) { 
    $this->em->getRepository('App:Table')->findAll();
  }
}
```

Credits to @profm2 for providing the comment and the code sample.

Comment: I had that one figured out already, but as a newb, I couldn't answer my own question. You can't get the container in the constructor, as it doesn't exist yet. It all works beautifully if you retrieve the container in the execute method. After that, you have access to your Entities the usual way:

    $myEntities = $em->getRepository('Acme\DemoBundle:Myentity')->findAll();

Comment: With the latest version ->getEntityManager(); is now deprecated in favor of ->getManager();

Comment: Remember to extend ContainerAwareCommand instead of Command in order to access getContainer() method

Comment: AND the command class must be in the command folder eg: AppBundle\Command package AND you must call the command using "bin/console mycommand" see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#automatically-registering-commands

Comment: In Symfony 4, create a __constructor with a EntityManagerInterface variable.  This variable will be accessible in the rest of your commands.  This follows the autowiring/dependencyInjection scheme.

Comment: @profm2 OK with you if I copy verbatim your comment in the answer? I don't do much Symfony nowaday.

Comment: `class UserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    private $em;
    public function __construct(?string $name = null, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    protected function configure()
    { **name, desc, help code here** }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    { $this->em->getRepository('App:Table')->findAll(); **etc etc** }
}`

Comment: @Matt Sure thing.  The code above is for Symfony 4.0.

Comment: A small addendum: don't forget to put the `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;` at the top

Comment: ContainerAwareCommand is deprecated since 4.2 - any solution for the use later on?

Answer (score 10):

extends your command class from ContainerAwareCommand instead of Command

```
class YourCmdCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
```

and get entity manager like this :

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Comment: ContainerAwareCommand is deprecated since 4.2 - any solution for the use later on?

Comment: @Isengo show other more recents responses because my suggestion are too old

Comment: @Isengo As of Symfony 4.2 you can inject the Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface into the Command.

Answer (score 3):

I know that Matt's answer solved the question, But if you've more than one entity manager, you can use this:

Make model.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services         http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<services>
    <service id="EM_NAME.entity_manager" alias="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</services>
</container>
```

Then load this file in your DI extension

```
$loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('model.xml');
```

Then you can use it anywhere.
In Console Command execute:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('EM_NAME.entity_manager');
```

and don't forget at end to :

```
$em->flush();
```

You can now use it as a argument in another service in services.yml:

```
services:
    SOME_SERVICE:
        class: %parameter.class%
        arguments:
            - @EM_NAME.entity_manager
```

Hope this help someone.