# Getting Service Container in Symfony 2 Console Command gives "getKernel() on a non-object"

Tags: symfony, console-application

In the `configure()` function, I tried to get the service container

```
class SetQuotaCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    protected function configure() {
        parent::configure();
        die(get_class($this->getContainer()));
```

> `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getKernel() on a non-object in ...\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand.php on line 37`

Do I need to do something different?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that it works if I call `getContainer` in `execute()`. But I wonder if its possible to `getContainer()` in `configure()`. I want to get a configuration parameter for use in `addOption` default value argument.

Otherwise I could use

```
$param1 = $input->getOption('param1') ? : $container->getParameter('param1');
```

Which appears abit more un-intuitive?

Comment: I think the problem is how you're doing it. Adding an option basing on a configuration value isn't a very good solution. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: I am wanting to set the defaults in parameters.ini. Something accessible through application and console. Though on 2nd thought, perhaps I could get away with a hardcoded default ...  hmm ... whats wrong with my way of doing it though?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. There's nothing wrong with your way of doing it. I think the only solution might be to set the default value to ```false``` in ```configure()``` and then set it manually in ```execute()```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears service container has not been initialized in `configure`. I can access it in `execute`.

As for defaults for console options, I can use something like

```
$opt1 = $input->getOption('opt1') ? : $default;
```

In many cases Symfony2 allows you to set a default value when retrieving parameters/variables. So a shortcut for the above mentioned solution would simply be:

```
$opt1 = $input->getOption('opt1', $default);
```

---

*Just putting this as an answer so I can close this if theres no other answers.*

Answer (score 21):

Call `$this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();` in execute().
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7517803/297679

Comment: `$this->container` has private access, so you can't set it in an extending class

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the information I found on Google (including this thread) nothing seems to worked. I finally figured out why I wasn't able to get a kernel.

In a 1:1 copy from the docs, i created a file application.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// application.php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/app/AppKernel.php';

use X\SnmpBundle\Command\GreetCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new GreetCommand());
$application->run();
```

And then execute the application by running:

./application.php this:that or php application.php this:that

This didn't work for me. For some reason the kernel is not available when doing this. However, it is when I run the application using:

php app/console this:that

My guess is that running app app/console does a lot more then my application.php does, such as starting a kernel.

With running the app as "php app/console this:that" everything works fine and I am able to use:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

which was what I needed.