# Use Doctrine in Service

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, bundle

I need to use doctrine inside my service.

When I try to get it with this code `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();` I catch this error :

> Call to undefined method Acme\CrawlerBundle\Services\getTrainingsService::getDoctrine()

How can I finally make the Doctrine work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the entity manager as an argument to your service like this:

```
    your_service:
        class: %your_class.class%
        arguments:
          - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: But I need to run my service from console command. Will it work normally?

Comment: Is this what you want? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512425/how-to-use-my-entities-and-entity-managers-in-symfony-2-console-command)